# Speculative execution Mapreduce/Spark

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, speculative-execution

I know Hadoop/Spark framework will detect failed or slow machines and execute the same tasks on different machine. How will (On what basis) framework identifies the 
slow running machines. Is there any kind of stats for the framework to decide?

Can someone shed light some light here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MapReduce model is to break jobs into tasks and run the tasks in parallel to
make the overall job execution time smaller than it would be if the tasks ran
sequentially.

`yarn.app.mapreduce.am.job.task.estimator.class`- When MapReduce model lunch a new job this property and implementation is being used to estimate the task completion time at runtime. The estimated completion time for a task should be less than a minute. If a task is running beyond this estimated time it can mark as slow running task.

`yarn.app.mapreduce.am.job.speculator.class` - This property is being used
to implementing the speculative execution policy.

Answer (score 2):

Spark.speculation   default value is false  If you set to "true", performs speculative execution of tasks. This means if one or more tasks are running slowly in a stage, they will be re-launched.

[image]

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

You can add these flags to your spark-submit, passing them under --conf  e.g.:

```
spark-submit \
--conf "spark.speculation=true" \
--conf "spark.speculation.multiplier=5" \
--conf "spark.speculation.quantile=0.90" \
--class "org.asyncified.myClass" "path/to/Vaquarkhanjar.jar"
```

**Note :**
Spark driver is spending a lot of time in speculation when managing a large number of tasks. enable it only if needed.